# Spring Boot 3 with GraphQL API on AWS Lambda: Encountering HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, graphql

### Scenario

I've tried to deploy a simple GraphQL API using spring-boot-starter-graphql and aws-serverless-java-conainer-springboot3 to AWS lambda with AWS HTTP API Gateway in front of it.
When I run it on a local environment using Tomcat, the request is processed normally.
However, when I deploy it on AWS Lambda, I get an org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: No content to map due to end-of-input error.

It seems error occurs while handling request.

I've been trying to solve it for three-full-days, but it hasn't been resolved. Any help would be appreciated.

### Versions

*Serverless Java Container version*: `2.0.0-M1`

*Implementations:* `Spring Boot 3`

*Framework version:* `SpringBoot 3.1.0`

*Frontend service:* `HTTP API`

*Deployment method:* `Console`

### Expected behavior

200 response should come when a request is sent to http api gateway url using curl.

```
curl 'https://[APIGATEWAY_URL]/graphql' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Origin: altair://-' --data-binary '{"query":"query example{\n  exampleQuery(input: { id: 1 }) {\n    ok\n  }\n}\n","variables":{}}' --compressed
```

### Actual behavior

An error occurs as shown in the log below.

### Steps to reproduce

This is the very small 5-class project repository that can reproduce the error.
https://github.com/2012160085/photomanagement

### Full log output

```
START RequestId: 5beefda9-8340-4539-a1b1-c1e154571024 Version: $LATEST
--
2023-05-31T07:18:56.999Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.AwsProxyHttpServletRequest@450794b4
2023-05-31T07:18:57.000Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/graphql", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-31T07:18:57.000Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.function.RequestPredicates       : Method "[GET]" does not match against value "POST"
2023-05-31T07:18:57.000Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.function.RequestPredicates       : Method "[POST]" matches against value "POST"
2023-05-31T07:18:57.000Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.function.RequestPredicates       : Pattern "/graphql" matches against value "/graphql"
2023-05-31T07:18:57.000Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.function.RequestPredicates       : Content-Type "[application/json]" matches against value "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
2023-05-31T07:18:57.000Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.function.RequestPredicates       : Accept "[application/graphql-response+json, application/json, application/graphql+json]" matches against value "[application/json]"
2023-05-31T07:18:57.000Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.servlet.function.RouterFunctions   : Predicate "((POST && /graphql) && (Content-Type: application/json && Accept: [application/graphql-response+json, application/json, application/graphql+json]))" matches against "HTTP POST /graphql"
2023-05-31T07:18:57.000Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.f.support.RouterFunctionMapping  : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.servlet.GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration$Lambda$909/0x0000000801c42aa0@332a7fce
2023-05-31T07:18:57.001Z DEBUG 8 --- [           main] o.s.g.server.webmvc.GraphQlHttpHandler   : Executing: document='query example{
exampleQuery(input: { id: 1 }) {
ok
}
}
', operationName='example', id=a1e5941b-7608-2e7e-389f-de1c93d105df, Locale=ko
2023-05-31T07:18:57.003Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'exampleController'
2023-05-31T07:18:57.003Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.graphql.data.method.HandlerMethod    : Arguments: [TestInput(id=1)]
2023-05-31T07:18:57.003Z DEBUG 8 --- [           main] o.s.g.server.webmvc.GraphQlHttpHandler   : Execution complete
2023-05-31T07:18:57.004Z DEBUG 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.request.async.WebAsyncManager    : Started async request
2023-05-31T07:18:57.004Z DEBUG 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.request.async.WebAsyncManager    : Async result set, dispatch to /graphql
2023-05-31T07:18:57.004Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ASYNC" dispatch for POST "/graphql", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-31T07:18:57.004Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.function.RequestPredicates       : Method "[GET]" does not match against value "POST"
2023-05-31T07:18:57.004Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.function.RequestPredicates       : Method "[POST]" matches against value "POST"
2023-05-31T07:18:57.004Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.function.RequestPredicates       : Pattern "/graphql" matches against value "/graphql"
2023-05-31T07:18:57.004Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.function.RequestPredicates       : Content-Type "[application/json]" matches against value "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
2023-05-31T07:18:57.004Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.function.RequestPredicates       : Accept "[application/graphql-response+json, application/json, application/graphql+json]" matches against value "[application/json]"
2023-05-31T07:18:57.004Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.servlet.function.RouterFunctions   : Predicate "((POST && /graphql) && (Content-Type: application/json && Accept: [application/graphql-response+json, application/json, application/graphql+json]))" matches against "HTTP POST /graphql"
2023-05-31T07:18:57.004Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.f.support.RouterFunctionMapping  : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.servlet.GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration$Lambda$909/0x0000000801c42aa0@332a7fce
2023-05-31T07:18:57.005Z  WARN 8 --- [           main] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: No content to map due to end-of-input]
2023-05-31T07:18:57.005Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2023-05-31T07:18:57.005Z DEBUG 8 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 400, headers={}
2023-05-31T07:18:57.005Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2023-05-31T07:18:57.005Z DEBUG 8 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 400, headers={}
2023-05-31T07:18:57.005Z TRACE 8 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.AwsProxyHttpServletRequest@450794b4
2023-05-31T07:18:57.005Z  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.internal.LambdaContainerHandler  : 222.237.84.246 null- null [31/05/2023:07:18:56Z] "POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 400 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) AltairGraphQLClient/5.0.20 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.0.10 Safari/537.36" combined
END RequestId: 5beefda9-8340-4539-a1b1-c1e154571024
REPORT RequestId: 5beefda9-8340-4539-a1b1-c1e154571024  Duration: 9.80 ms   Billed Duration: 10 ms  Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 192 MB
```